# Why the animation of KeyboardDismissMode is weird

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I add this code to enable scroll to dismiss keyboard

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

But the keyboard always lose the animation when it was about to exit,
like at this position
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKf1H.png)

iOS version is 14.4

Answer (score 1):

You can dismiss your keyboard when you scroll with simply using `UIScrollViewDelegate` method scrollViewDidScroll like below:

```
extension yourClass: UIScrollViewDelegate {
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     self.searchbar.resignFirstResponder() // Your textField or searchBar etc.
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. I don't know why